# JavaFx error when i try to login to database from azure

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans-8

i have some problem with `javaFx`, when i press the button "login" it gives me this error.

```
Executing C:\Users\Iuli\Desktop\RAU Social Media\RAU_socialmedia\dist\run1236271702\RAU_socialmedia.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre/bin/java
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at rau_socialmedia.FXMLDocumentController.handlelogin(FXMLDocumentController.java:54)
    ... 58 more
```

I've been learning `javafx` for a while, and I've stuck to that error. I tried, I searched and I do not understand why this error is occurring.
I'll put you down and rest on the components.

> FXMLDocumentController

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package rau_socialmedia;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.*;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import java.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 *
 * @author FISHU
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private Label messagelogin;
    @FXML
    private Label errorlabel;
    @FXML
    private Label conlabel;
      @FXML
    private Label txtEmail;
        @FXML
    private Label txtPass;

    private PreparedStatement ppSs;
    private Connection con = null;

    @FXML
    private void handleClose(ActionEvent event)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    @FXML
    private void handlelogin(ActionEvent event) throws SQLException
    {

    con = dba.DBCOnnection.pMartConnection();

   String sql_query = "SELECT * FROM [login] where email='"+txtEmail.getText()+
           "' and parola='"+txtPass.getText()+"' ";

      ppSs = con.prepareStatement(sql_query);
     boolean status = ppSs.execute();

     if(status){
        messagelogin.setText("asda");
        errorlabel.setOpacity(1);
     }
     else{
         messagelogin.setText("nada");
     }
    }
    @FXML
    private void handleregister(ActionEvent event)
    {
        messagelogin.setText("");
        conlabel.setOpacity(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    }    

}
```

> rau_socialmedia.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package rau_socialmedia;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

/**
 *
 * @author FISHU
 */
public class RAU_socialmedia extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

> fxmlDocument.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXPasswordField?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.BoxBlur?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Line?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="rau_socialmedia.FXMLDocumentController">
   <children>
      <ImageView fitHeight="600.0" fitWidth="1000.0" layoutX="-2.0">
         <image>
            <Image url="@images/dummy-6.jpg" />
         </image>
         <effect>
            <BoxBlur iterations="2" />
         </effect>
      </ImageView>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="567.0" layoutY="129.0" prefHeight="354.0" prefWidth="401.0">
         <children>
            <JFXTextField focusColor="#2bc5e7" labelFloat="true" layoutX="26.0" layoutY="49.0" maxWidth="327.0" minWidth="301.0" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="318.0" promptText="E-mail" unFocusColor="BLACK" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="25.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="25.0">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Times New Roman Bold" size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </JFXTextField>
            <JFXPasswordField focusColor="#2cc7e5" labelFloat="true" layoutX="25.0" layoutY="117.0" maxWidth="318.0" minWidth="165.0" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="318.0" promptText="Parolă" unFocusColor="BLACK" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="25.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="25.0">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Times New Roman Bold" size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </JFXPasswordField>
            <JFXButton layoutX="34.0" layoutY="202.0" onAction="#handlelogin" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="150.0" ripplerFill="#3bbdd7" style="-fx-background-color: #fffcfc;" text="Loghează-te" textFill="#030000" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="25.0">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Times New Roman Bold" size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </JFXButton>
            <JFXButton layoutX="222.0" layoutY="202.0" onAction="#handleregister" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="150.0" ripplerFill="#3bbdd7" style="-fx-background-color: #fffcfc;" text="Înregistrează-te" textFill="#030000" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="25.0">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Times New Roman Bold" size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </JFXButton>
            <Label fx:id="errorlabel" layoutX="25.0" layoutY="234.0" opacity="0.0" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="351.0" text="Datele introduse nu sunt corecte !" textFill="RED">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Times New Roman Bold" size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label fx:id="conlabel" layoutX="25.0" layoutY="288.0" opacity="0.0" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="376.0" text="Felicitari, te-ai inregistrat cu succes!">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Times New Roman Bold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="27.0" layoutY="108.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@images/logo-URA-2017.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Label fx:id="messagelogin" layoutX="47.0" layoutY="262.0" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Welcome to">
         <font>
            <Font name="Times New Roman Bold" size="25.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="41.0" layoutY="289.0" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="262.0" text="RAU Social Media">
         <font>
            <Font name="Times New Roman Bold" size="22.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Line endX="100.0" layoutX="545.0" layoutY="277.0" rotate="90.0" startX="-100.0" />
      <JFXButton layoutX="949.0" layoutY="14.0" onAction="#handleClose" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="26.0" ripplerFill="#3bbdd7" style="-fx-background-color: #fffcfc;" text="X" textFill="#030000">
         <font>
            <Font name="Arial" size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </JFXButton>
   </children>
   <opaqueInsets>
      <Insets />
   </opaqueInsets>
</AnchorPane>
```

> packages > dba > DBCOnnection.java

```
package dba;


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Iuli
 */
public class DBCOnnection {
    public static Connection pMartConnection(){
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://developbuilding.database.windows.net:1433;database=jdata;user=devbuild@developbuilding;password=Developbuilding@;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBCOnnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return con;
    }

}
```

I have on my libraries `sqljdbc41.jar` and `jfeonix.jar` driver.

Comment: I don't see `txtEmail` and `txtPass` anywhere in your fxml. Furthermore better use placeholders in when generating the `PreparedStatement` and use e.g. `PreparedStatement.setString` to inset the values. Otherwise you may get a nasty surprise, if a string you receive from one of your `TextField`s contains quotes.

Comment: Also it would be better to document the return type of the `pMartConnection` method. After all you don't use it properly in the `FXMLDocumentController` class: You need to check for `null` in this class, since any error when creating the connection makes it impossible to continue properly with the `handlelogin` method and you don't get a exception; you simply log it and then ignore it in the `pMartConnection` method.